# Is there an official organization for discussing or releasing standard markdown syntax?

Tags: syntax, standards, markdown, organization

Recently, when I use github I met so many cases that I need to use markdown for my documents. Such as any wiki and GFM(github favored markdown), `*.md` files in github page base on jekyll, and just like writing here, etc. And I love writing documents by this syntax!

But all the markdown engines are different in many details: GFM doesn't support definition list syntax; maruku in jekyll doesn't support auto-generating ID of headers for TOC; kramdown, multimarkdown... and so on. Engines are also written in many languages like ruby, PHP, Java even more.

I found chaos in markdown world, just like I must write my CSS and JavaScript to support so many browsers for compatibility, not better, and even worse!

So I think of that like my title, if there is an official organization working for making markdown syntax to be standard, like W3C for web standard, the world in markdown would be better than ever!

Then anyone could submit their suggestion for new syntax to the ORG, and the ORG could review them and build a standard syntax criterion for developers. At that time, all the users like us could make less choice for which engines should use. And we can write once, use anywhere!

So comes my question, is there? or someone would like to create it?

Comment: The only standard now is the behavior of the original perl script found here at http://daringfireball.net/projects/downloads/Markdown_1.0.1.zip . It would be nice if there's an organization for the standardization of markdown. Here's a bug of most markdown implementation: https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/64

Comment: @yegle: From everything I've read, the "official" original spec is abandonware, with many bugs and oversights that need improvement.  Is there a *de facto* standard for those improvements?  A fork that is used by the majority of people?

Comment: @edolith no. That's a sad answer. Maybe you can consider github's GFM. It's not a de facto standard, but at least it's not just copying everything the original perl script is doing(bugs are also copied).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [community group](http://www.w3.org/community/markdown/) has been created at W3C to create a specification for Markdown.

The current standard is generally seen as [this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) however  that has a different scope to the working group.

Answer (score 2):

The situation has changed since 2012 for the better!

[CommonMark](http://commonmark.org), which was originally intended to be aptly called “Standard Markdown”, formally specifies the syntax and semantics of the classic language, introducing several clarifications and some alterations from either the original prose or the reference implementation `markdown.pl` or both.

This specification *may* also document extensions in the future, but that’s clearly not the primary goal currently. [Markua](http://markua.com/) is another open specification which builds upon CommonMark but implements useful extensions from the start – it derives from [Leanpub](https://leanpub.com/help/manual). 
The [Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#pandocs-markdown) describes several common features of Pandoc, [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcher.github.io/MultiMarkdown-4/syntax.html) (MMD), [PHP Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) and [Github flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) (GFM), but not [Maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/maruku.html), [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html) and other popular ones.

[Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/) is a web service by John MacFarlane that tries Markdown code with several engines, hosted and configured by their developers, and compares the resulting HTML.

A supplementary spec is [Critic Markup](http://criticmarkup.com/users-guide.php) which describes syntax for deletion, addition, highlighting and comments that can be used with a variety of simple markup languages.